# List cant clear! C#

Tags: c#, sockets, listbox

```
//selects the movie option, this will populate the movie lists (titles only)
    private void btnMovies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = 0;
        string titles = null;
        byte[] dataSend = new byte[1024];
        byte[] dataReceive = new byte[1024];
        string[] split = null;
        movieList.Items.Clear();
        movietitles.Clear();
        try
        {

            Array.Clear(dataSend, 0, dataSend.Length);
            dataSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("movies");
            socket.Send(dataSend);
            size = socket.Receive(dataReceive);//receive movie titles
            titles = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceive, 0, size);
            char[] separators = { ';' };
            split = titles.Split(separators);

            for (int i =0;i<split.Count();i++)
            {
                movietitles.Add(split[i]);
            }

            foreach (string smovie in movietitles)
            {
                movieList.Items.Add(smovie);
            }


        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Unable to connect to server";
            lblError.Text += ex;
        }

        pnlMovies.Visible = true;


    }
```

So whats happening here is that im populating the movieList (listbox) with movie titles in the movietitles  list. However everytime I press the button movies again it populates it again without clearing the previous one, even though i cleared it. I printed out the .count for the movietitles and it increases everytime by double, so its definetely the problem.

I already .Clear() it, so im not sure what else I can do. I reset all the variables too but nothing works. Thanks!

Comment: How does sockets factor in?  Is this ASP.NET web forms?

Comment: What kind of UI technology? WF? WPF? WebForms?

Comment: If these are TCP sockets, which I think they are, then the receive code is wrong too. TCP is a streaming protocol, you must be prepared to receive data in multiple chunks. There is no garantee you receive everything in one call to receive.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it would probably be better if you bind your ListBox to a datasource.  Something like:

```
//populate your List with your movie titles
private List<String> movieTitles = new List<string>() { "movie1", "movie2", "movie3" };
//Then bind the datasource
movieList.ItemSource = movieTitles;
```

Comment: If your going to down-vote my answer you could at least give an explanation

Comment: It does not work because if it is WPF you at least need an observablecollection if the list is going to be changed from code. Otherwise the GUI will not show any changes. I did not downvote but your answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response and clarification Philip.  That makes sense but the UI was not specified by the OP so I was simply taking a guess.  I don't care that I'm wrong but I can't learn if someone doesn't tell me WHY I am wrong.